# Keyboard input with pynput on a Mac

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput, apple-m2

`keyboard` fails on a Mac and I would like to use `pynput` but fail to execute successfully.

```py
from pynput import keyboard
import time

def on_press(key, ts, gt_forward, rb, extent, aoi, aoibuffer, jparams):
    if key == keyboard.Key.enter:
        print("\nYou pressed Enter... we continue with osm_LoD1_3DCityModel.")
        
        ...lots of code that saves something.
        
def on_release(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

def main():
    start = time.time()
    
    ...code here...

    print('')
    print("Have a look at the matplotlib render that might highlight errors (red) in the 2D vectors.\n\nIf there are no challenges press 'Enter' to continue; else press 'Esc' to exit: ")

    with keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=lambda key: on_press(key, ts, gt_forward, rb, extent, aoi, aoibuffer, jparams),
            on_release= on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

    end = time.time()
    print('runtime:', str(timedelta(seconds=(end - start))))  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

`on_press` executes successfully and what I need gets written to file but the script does not move on to:

```py
end = time.time()
print('runtime:', str(timedelta(seconds=(end - start))))
```

I am not sure of the proper syntax.

Also will the revised script, with `pynput`, execute successfully on a Windows machine?

Comment: Please share your `pynput` code with us so we can help you better, "but fail to execute successfully" cannot tell us anything. If you don't have any code to show yet using `pynput`, then take a look [here](https://pypi.org/project/pynput) to see if you can get some code ready.